# Can I create a partial template specialization of of a class template matching enumeration types?

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization, explicit-specialization

I have a function template powered by a set of class template explicit specializations giving syntax like

```
abc.GetAs<DesiredType>("Name");
```

(where `GetAs<t>` is something like:

```
template<typename T>
T GetAs(wchar_t const* propName) const
{
    typedef Converter<T> Converter;
    auto thing = Get(propName);
    return Converter::Convert(thing);
}
```

)

I would like to have a specialization for `DesiredType` when that type is an enumeration, so that the returned type matches the underlying type of the enumeration (or `enum class`).

Is that possible or do clients just have to specify the underlying type themselves?

---

I'm trying to allow code like this:

```
enum class Example
{
    One,
    Two
}

int main()
{
    foo_ipc_class ic(L"/// Construct me");
    // Today, calls the primary template rather than an explicit
    // specialization for an integral type.
    Example ex = ic.GetAs<Example>(L"Property Name");
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, can you give an example of the desired functionality? Is [n3601](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) relevant?

Comment: @Mankarse: This is a library for some external interprocess communication mechanism which is not strongly typed. There are various explicit specializations of a class template, each of which contain the code necessary to convert from the interprocess communication version of the data (e.g. `VARIANT`) into C++ style types. Then there's a member function template calling the class template (in order to make partial specializations possible).

Comment: @BillyONeal: Can't you then introduce a partial specialization for that class that gets selected if the type is an enum? What's the definition of the primary class template?

Comment: @Andy: I don't know. I'm asking how one would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's impossible to partially specialise function templates, you'll have to change your implementation to use the "delegate-to-class" trick:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Class to delegate to
template <typename T, bool isEnum = std::is_enum<T>::value>
struct GetAs_Class {
  typedef your_return_type ReturnType;
  static ReturnType GetAs(your_parameters) { your_code; }
};

// Partial specialisation    
template <typename T>
struct GetAs_Class<T, true> {
  typedef specialisation_return_type ReturnType;
  static ReturnType GetAs(your_parameters) { specialisation_code; }
};


// Your function now delegates to the class
template <typename T>
typename GetAs_Class<T>::ReturnType GetAs(your_parameters) {
  return GetAs_Class<T>::GetAs(your_arguments);
}
```

Comment: It already does delegate to a class template. I just want to write an explicit specialization matching enumerations. That `bool isEnum` trick looks like what I needed.

Comment: @BillyONeal It uses C++11 type traits. Should you not have these, you can use those from Boost.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SFINAE to enable/disable overloads based on whether template parameter is an enum or not. [`std::is_enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) and [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) come handy. I wrote `GetAs` as a free function for simplicity:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct identity {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value, identity<T>>::type::type
GetAs(wchar_t const*)
{
    std::cout << "general\n";
    // return something
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::underlying_type<T>>::type::type
GetAs(wchar_t const*)
{
    std::cout << "enum\n";
    // return something
}

enum class E : short {
};

int main()
{
    GetAs<int>(L"hm");
    GetAs<E>(L"hm");
}
```

It's pretty ugly, but so is delegating to a class to mimic partial specializations of function templates, IMO :)

Comment: The main reason I used a class is that this conversion machinery is used in multiple places; and the SFINAE would need to be done in each place.